Sharepoint List multi-choice column export to CSV with transpose
I have a SharePoint list with a multi-choice column and I am using Power Automate to export this list to CSV on one-drive regularly. I need to transpose the multi-choice column from an array to different rows. So example:
From this view in SharePoint list :



Multi-choice column Fruits
Quantity needed
Name




Apple, Banana, Grape
10
John


Grape, Apple
200
Mark



converted to in my exported CSV file:



Fruits
Quantity
Name




Apple
10
John


Banana
10
John


Grape
10
John


Grape
200
Mark


Apple
200
Mark



Is there a way to use power automation to do this?
I have been using 'splice' to split the array into different rows using power automate but this does not fulfill what I need which is the information in different columns.
What I have:



Fruits1
Fruits2
Fruits2
Quantity
Name




Apple
Banana
Grape
10
John




You can achieve your desired output by using the Apply each step in the following way:

Initialize an Array to store your output
Use the Parse JSON Step to access your array and its internal attributes—the schema you can pick from the output of your data source.
Now you can iterate over your records (in my example I have given it name as Array):
Inside this use the Compose step to split your Multi-choice column Fruits column. Following is an example expression: split(items('Apply_to_each')? ['MultiChoice'], ',')
Now again you need to iterate over these split values, to generate individual records. Now JSON parsing will come in handy, to access the Quantity needed and Name to create new records.
Now, use the Append to Array step, to create a new record (inside your second apply each).

Like this:

The Object array should give you data in the desired format.
